# Beautiful soup Python extracing data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python. Long time user of stackoverflow but first time posting a question.
I am trying to extract data from website using beautifulsoup.
[Sample Code where I want to extract is (listed in and tagged in data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AASRq.jpg)

The was able to extract in to list but I am unable to extract the acutal data.
the goal here is to extract 
**Listed in:** Nail Polish Subscription Boxes, Subscription Boxes for Beauty Products, Subscription Boxes for Women
**Tagged in:** Makeup, Beauty, Nail polish

Can you please tell me how to achive it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

l1=[]
url='http://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/julep-maven'
source_code=requests.get(url)
plain_text=source_code.text
soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all('p'):    
       l1.append(item.contents)
search='\nListed in:\n'
for a in l1:
    if a[0] in ('\nTagged in:\n','\nListed in:\n'):
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `lxml`, why not use it in a more direct manner (`lxml` is believed to be faster than `BeautifulSoup`):

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url='http://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/julep-maven'
source_code=requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(source_code.content) #parses the html
paras = tree.xpath('//div[@class="box-information"]/p') #gets the para elements

# This loop prints the desired para elements' text.
for ele in paras[1:]:
    print(ele.text_content())
```

Output:

```
Listed in:
Nail Polish Subscription Boxes, Subscription Boxes for Beauty Products, Subscription Boxes for Women


Tagged in:
Makeup, Beauty, Nail polish
```

Note: The site is captcha-protected, so you may need to copy the source html from your browser's dev tools as a string and use it in `tree = html.fromstring(copied_string)` to make this code work.

Comment: Thank You Sam for your response. The reason for using lxml is because of python was  throwing an error   (BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})).
I am not familiar with lxml. Is this another package like beautifulsoup?

Comment: @uraju Yes and it's faster! Can you provide more information about the error?

Comment: Env35\lib\runpy.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))

Comment: Thank You Sam for  your inputs. Can you please help me how to call it in a return statetment,instead of print(ele.text_content()). I want the result in return statement.  I am getting an error as  return' outside function

Comment: `import requests
from lxml import html

url='http://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/julep-maven'
source_code=requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(source_code.content) #parses the html
paras = tree.xpath('//div[@class="box-information"]/p') #gets the para elements

# This loop prints the desired para elements' text.
for ele in paras[1:]:
    a=[]
    a.append(ele.text_content())
    return a`

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: When code throws an Error, it always helps to include the Error you got so others can reproduce the same Error. Did you get `line 13
    return a
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`? that's b/c `return`s need to be within a function block that gets called, like this: https://pastebin.com/B0swdFfb

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Tw2ghzfK   This is my complete program. I just want to print in One line and export it to CSV

Comment: @uraju downshift is right. If you still want to use a `return`, encapsulate your code within a function.

Comment: @uraju I think there are lots of problems with your code, one of them being that you're returning in the very first iteration of loops in functions.

Comment: It is working Sam except Listed /Tagged function values are showing up in a differnt line

Comment: @uraju Cool then, but if it's working, what's the problem? To get the output on the same line, use the `end=" "` argument in the `print()` function.

Comment: Thank You Sam and Downshift. I was able to fix the issue and export it ti excel in a single coloumn. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

import re
context = soup(text=re.compile(r'Listed in:'))

for item in context:
    listed_in = item.parent
    tagged_in = listed_in.find_next_siblings()[0]

print(listed_in.text.strip('\n').replace('\n', ''))
print(tagged_in.text.strip('\n').replace('\n', ''))
```

will display all in one line:

```
Listed in:Nail Polish Subscription Boxes, Subscription Boxes for Beauty Products, Subscription Boxes for Women, Tagged in: Makeup, Beauty, Nail polish
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You Downshit. I have tried this method earlier, however the list[3:5] is not consistent. Sometimes I find the tags in 2:5  or 1:3.Sams method works but I am unable to create a return object of the list.I have created  each content as function and I am calling them in the main program. My end goal is to create a list  of all the items like (description, price,ratings,url,tagged,listed) for each product and export it to the excel

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @uraju. Your requirements are very understandable. I've updated my answer, though I'm not sure this next solution is any more dynamic than my previous example.

Comment: pastebin.com/Tw2ghzfK This is my complete program. I just want to print in One line and export it to CSV @downshift. Thanks for the all the help.

Comment: Yes I'm happy to try to help you. I ran the code in your link, it seems to run fine. what doesn't work correctly?

Comment: I think the Listed /Tagged function values are showing up on different lines because the text still contains `'\n'` newline characters. Remove them should fix it. Try using `return listed_in.text.strip('\n').replace('\n', '')`, and `return tagged_in.text.strip('\n').replace('\n', '')`